# Can I select a region for the screenshot via keyboard in import

Tags: imagemagick, screenshot

Can I select a region for the screenshot via keyboard in import from ImageMagick? If yes, how can I do it? If no, what can I use instead of import?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any method that would allow you to select a region using just the keyboard.

You can use the following method to get a screenshot via command line specifying a region. For example if you wanted to get a region that's 400x200 of the active window you could use this command:

```
$ import -window "$(xdotool getwindowfocus)" -crop 400x200+0+0 \
    +repage image1.png
```

[image: ss of terminal window]

Answer (score 0):

I am using i3, and it just works. Just call import with filename:

```
$ import dummyfile.png
```

Select with mouse. Done.

Comment: The question is about keyboard, not mouse.