# How do I take a screenshot of a specific screen area from the command line?

Tags: shell-script, screenshot

I do not want to have to interactively select the area I want to take a screenshot of. I would rather do something like `--area=x,y,height,width`. Is there any screenshot utility that can do this?

Comment: Look at my A'er on this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/command-for-taking-a-screenshot-to-a-new-file/92297#92297

Comment: Here too - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123803/can-i-select-a-region-for-the-screenshot-via-keyboard-in-import/123989#123989

Comment: I'm not aware of a region capability, you can do windows though.

Comment: Possible dup - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123803/can-i-select-a-region-for-the-screenshot-via-keyboard-in-import/123989#123989

Comment: Another possible dup - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233345/how-can-i-easily-make-screenshots-of-screen-regions-on-arch-linux-with-i3-wm

Comment: There's a script on this AU Q&A that has a script called scrot_extend that does exactly what you want - https://askubuntu.com/questions/585455/taking-screenshot-of-a-specific-area-from-the-command-line

Comment: More here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156039/screen-capture-application-for-rhel6-5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command for taking a screenshot to a new file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92286/command-for-taking-a-screenshot-to-a-new-file)

Comment: I do not see an answer in that proposed duplicate that answers this question, @vfbsilva.

Comment: @JeffSchaller shutter allows you to select a given subscreen to copy

Comment: Is it in the advanced options? It’s not described in the answer there.